# Somebody explains all these divs

Tags: blogger

***please somebody explain to what is all these divs!
   because i don't understand how they work together...
   it's 'simple template' in blogger***

```
<div class='body-fauxcolumns'>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer body-fauxcolumn-outer'>
        <div class='cap-top'>
        <div class='cap-left'></div>
        <div class='cap-right'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='fauxborder-left'>
        <div class='fauxborder-right'></div>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class='cap-bottom'>
        <div class='cap-left'></div>
        <div class='cap-right'></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class='content'>
        <div class='content-fauxcolumns'>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer content-fauxcolumn-outer'>
        <div class='cap-top'>
        <div class='cap-left'></div>
        <div class='cap-right'></div>
        </div>
```

thanks!

Comment: Mainly the `Faux Columns` technique  helps in Fluid Width Equal Height Columns , This article should be helpful - https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score -1):

It's tags that describe the design of the widgets in Layout section of the Dashboard.